# Attach a SVG to another SVG and make it responsive

Tags: html, css, svg, nuxt.js

This hexagon is an SVG and I'm changing the background of it by displaying the picture that the user uploads.

[image: Hexagon for profile picture]

And it works fine but now my issue is that in this application there is a system of different types of frames that will be added outside of the hexagon take this as an example of what I want to do

[image]

in the middle of the photo, there is a hexagon and there is where the user photo goes, so let's say I want to attach the frame that is around the hexagon, so how can I do it??

btw it can't be the same SVG because I would like to have it separate because I want to call the frame by using an "img" tag because the SVG code is to extensive for some frames and there will be a lot so I just want to know how can a attach it to the main hexagon and making it responsive.

This is what I would like to achieve

[image]

Here you have the SVG code for the hexagon and the wings otherwise you can use the SVG you prefer I just need that someone explain to me how can do it please

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Server error</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name=viewport>
</head>
<body>
<!-- here is the hexagon svg code -->
<svg
    height="8rem"
    width="8rem"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 260 300"
  >
    <path
      d="M250.042 232.281L138.415 297.09C132.132 300.738 124.366 300.691 118.127 296.97L9.75357 232.319C3.70481 228.71 0 222.186 0 215.143V84.8573C0 77.814 3.7048 71.2899 9.75356 67.6814L118.127 3.03046C124.366 -0.691467 132.132 -0.737547 138.415 2.91007L250.042 67.7185C256.206 71.2974 260 77.8867 260 85.0148V214.985C260 222.113 256.206 228.703 250.042 232.281Z"
      fill="black" />
</svg>

<!-- here is the wings svg code -->

<svg width="279" height="121" viewBox="0 0 279 121" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M190.289 41.9552L201.006 59.27L218.086 48.9477L235.167 38.6254C235.167 38.6254 239.016 27.4383 239.855 19.9787C240.757 11.9622 238.516 0 238.516 0C238.516 0 231.818 15.9829 215.073 24.6404C198.328 33.2978 190.289 41.9552 190.289 41.9552Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<path d="M238.268 0.704249C238.247 0.567802 238.34 0.440072 238.476 0.418956C238.613 0.397841 238.741 0.491336 238.762 0.627783L238.268 0.704249ZM196.317 51.9446C196.189 51.7299 196.189 51.7299 196.189 51.7298C196.189 51.7298 196.189 51.7297 196.189 51.7297C196.189 51.7295 196.19 51.7293 196.19 51.7289C196.192 51.7282 196.193 51.7272 196.196 51.7257C196.201 51.7229 196.208 51.7186 196.217 51.7128C196.237 51.7012 196.266 51.6837 196.304 51.6602C196.381 51.6133 196.497 51.5424 196.651 51.4472C196.959 51.2567 197.418 50.9687 198.024 50.5793C199.236 49.8004 201.033 48.6157 203.376 46.9941C208.06 43.7509 214.921 38.7597 223.623 31.771L223.936 32.1608C215.224 39.1572 208.354 44.1554 203.66 47.4052C201.313 49.0301 199.511 50.2179 198.294 50.9999C197.686 51.3908 197.224 51.6803 196.914 51.8723C196.759 51.9682 196.642 52.0398 196.564 52.0875C196.525 52.1113 196.495 52.1292 196.475 52.1411C196.465 52.1471 196.458 52.1516 196.453 52.1546C196.45 52.1561 196.448 52.1573 196.447 52.1581C196.446 52.1584 196.446 52.1587 196.446 52.1589C196.445 52.159 196.445 52.1591 196.445 52.1592C196.445 52.1592 196.445 52.1593 196.317 51.9446ZM223.623 31.771C232.283 24.8169 235.94 17.0419 237.435 11.0114C238.183 7.99469 238.391 5.41289 238.411 3.58714C238.422 2.67435 238.385 1.95085 238.347 1.45686C238.327 1.20988 238.307 1.02032 238.292 0.893192C238.285 0.829632 238.279 0.781686 238.274 0.749985C238.272 0.734134 238.27 0.722345 238.269 0.714696C238.269 0.710871 238.268 0.708082 238.268 0.706337C238.268 0.705465 238.268 0.704854 238.268 0.704506C238.268 0.704331 238.268 0.704267 238.268 0.70418C238.268 0.704181 238.268 0.704249 238.515 0.666016C238.762 0.627783 238.762 0.627982 238.762 0.628247C238.762 0.628424 238.762 0.628756 238.762 0.629108C238.762 0.629814 238.762 0.630784 238.762 0.632015C238.763 0.634478 238.763 0.63799 238.764 0.642541C238.765 0.651644 238.767 0.664903 238.77 0.682241C238.774 0.716915 238.781 0.767904 238.789 0.834575C238.805 0.967915 238.825 1.164 238.845 1.41779C238.885 1.92534 238.922 2.66382 238.911 3.59281C238.89 5.45063 238.679 8.0716 237.92 11.1317C236.402 17.2549 232.691 25.1299 223.936 32.1608L223.623 31.771Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
<path d="M199.667 100.561L203.016 82.5804C203.016 82.5804 219.762 70.5932 241.196 68.5954C262.63 66.5975 274.687 43.2891 274.687 43.2891C274.687 43.2891 271.337 97.8974 237.177 97.8974C203.016 97.8974 199.667 100.561 199.667 100.561Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear)"/>
<path d="M201.677 92.5698C201.565 92.3459 201.566 92.3458 201.566 92.3457C201.566 92.3457 201.566 92.3456 201.566 92.3454C201.567 92.3452 201.568 92.3448 201.568 92.3444C201.57 92.3435 201.573 92.3422 201.576 92.3405C201.583 92.3371 201.593 92.3321 201.607 92.3256C201.634 92.3126 201.674 92.2934 201.727 92.2684C201.833 92.2184 201.99 92.1452 202.2 92.0515C202.619 91.864 203.245 91.5947 204.076 91.2656C205.736 90.6073 208.213 89.7099 211.486 88.7503C218.032 86.8312 227.762 84.6635 240.506 83.6631L240.546 84.1616C227.837 85.1591 218.142 87.3201 211.627 89.2301C208.369 90.1852 205.907 91.0775 204.26 91.7304C203.436 92.0568 202.817 92.3234 202.404 92.5079C202.198 92.6002 202.043 92.672 201.94 92.7205C201.889 92.7448 201.85 92.7633 201.825 92.7756C201.812 92.7817 201.803 92.7863 201.797 92.7893C201.794 92.7909 201.791 92.792 201.79 92.7927C201.789 92.793 201.789 92.7933 201.788 92.7935C201.788 92.7935 201.788 92.7936 201.788 92.7936C201.788 92.7936 201.788 92.7936 201.677 92.5698ZM240.506 83.6631C253.1 82.6746 261.583 72.6205 266.931 62.7326C269.602 57.796 271.48 52.9198 272.691 49.2766C273.296 47.4554 273.735 45.9433 274.021 44.8871C274.165 44.3591 274.27 43.945 274.34 43.6634C274.375 43.5226 274.4 43.4149 274.417 43.3425C274.426 43.3064 274.432 43.2791 274.437 43.2609C274.439 43.2518 274.44 43.245 274.441 43.2405C274.442 43.2383 274.442 43.2366 274.442 43.2356C274.442 43.235 274.443 43.2346 274.443 43.2344C274.443 43.2342 274.443 43.2341 274.687 43.2891C274.93 43.344 274.93 43.3443 274.93 43.3446C274.93 43.3449 274.93 43.3455 274.93 43.3461C274.93 43.3474 274.929 43.3492 274.929 43.3517C274.928 43.3565 274.926 43.3637 274.924 43.3732C274.919 43.3922 274.913 43.4203 274.904 43.4573C274.887 43.5313 274.86 43.6407 274.825 43.7833C274.755 44.0684 274.648 44.4862 274.504 45.0182C274.215 46.0821 273.774 47.6032 273.165 49.4344C271.948 53.0959 270.059 58.0009 267.371 62.9704C262.003 72.8946 253.405 83.1522 240.546 84.1616L240.506 83.6631Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"/>
<path d="M198.995 59.2724L204.355 82.5808C204.355 82.5808 214.403 76.4209 249.233 69.9277C284.062 63.4345 278.703 4.66406 278.703 4.66406C278.703 4.66406 267.989 25.3087 239.187 36.6299C210.385 47.9512 198.995 59.2724 198.995 59.2724Z" fill="url(#paint4_linear)"/>
<path d="M201.674 73.2575C201.674 73.2575 213.731 63.9341 242.533 53.9448C271.335 43.9554 278.703 4.66406 278.703 4.66406" stroke="url(#paint5_linear)" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path d="M200.341 99.8944L194.982 111.216C194.982 111.216 230.482 117.209 247.228 107.22C263.973 97.2306 265.312 77.252 265.312 77.252C265.312 77.252 251.246 97.2306 234.501 95.8987C217.756 94.5668 200.341 99.8944 200.341 99.8944Z" fill="url(#paint6_linear)"/>
<path d="M198.329 105.222C198.329 105.222 209.046 103.224 231.15 103.224C253.254 103.224 265.98 76.5859 265.98 76.5859" stroke="url(#paint7_linear)" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
<path d="M84.0045 59.2724L78.6452 82.5808C78.6452 82.5808 68.5964 76.4209 33.7674 69.9277C-1.06154 63.4345 4.29675 4.66406 4.29675 4.66406C4.29675 4.66406 15.0114 25.3087 43.8133 36.6299C72.6153 47.9512 84.0045 59.2724 84.0045 59.2724Z" fill="url(#paint8_linear)"/>
<path d="M81.3215 73.2575C81.3215 73.2575 69.2648 63.9341 40.4629 53.9448C11.6609 43.9554 4.29297 4.66406 4.29297 4.66406" stroke="url(#paint9_linear)" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter1_d)">
<path d="M83.3306 100.559L79.9815 82.5785C79.9815 82.5785 63.2362 70.5913 41.8022 68.5934C20.3682 66.5955 8.31152 43.2871 8.31152 43.2871C8.31152 43.2871 11.6606 97.8955 45.8211 97.8955C79.9815 97.8955 83.3306 100.559 83.3306 100.559Z" fill="url(#paint10_linear)"/>
<path d="M81.3211 92.5678C81.4324 92.3439 81.4323 92.3439 81.4321 92.3438C81.432 92.3437 81.4318 92.3436 81.4315 92.3435C81.431 92.3432 81.4303 92.3429 81.4294 92.3424C81.4276 92.3415 81.425 92.3402 81.4215 92.3385C81.4146 92.3352 81.4044 92.3302 81.391 92.3237C81.3641 92.3106 81.3242 92.2915 81.2712 92.2665C81.1654 92.2165 81.0075 92.1432 80.7979 92.0495C80.3786 91.8621 79.7526 91.5928 78.9224 91.2636C77.262 90.6054 74.7848 89.708 71.5117 88.7484C64.9656 86.8292 55.2363 84.6615 42.4916 83.6611L42.4524 84.1596C55.1606 85.1571 64.8559 87.3181 71.3711 89.2282C74.6287 90.1832 77.0914 91.0756 78.7381 91.7284C79.5615 92.0549 80.1809 92.3214 80.5938 92.506C80.8002 92.5983 80.9549 92.6701 81.0577 92.7186C81.1091 92.7429 81.1475 92.7613 81.1729 92.7736C81.1856 92.7798 81.195 92.7844 81.2012 92.7874C81.2043 92.7889 81.2065 92.79 81.208 92.7907C81.2087 92.7911 81.2092 92.7913 81.2095 92.7915C81.2097 92.7916 81.2098 92.7916 81.2098 92.7917C81.2099 92.7917 81.2099 92.7917 81.3211 92.5678ZM42.4916 83.6611C29.8982 82.6727 21.4155 72.6186 16.0668 62.7306C13.3965 57.7941 11.518 52.9178 10.307 49.2747C9.70166 47.4535 9.26341 45.9414 8.97666 44.8852C8.83328 44.3571 8.72779 43.9431 8.65823 43.6614C8.62346 43.5206 8.59766 43.4129 8.5806 43.3406C8.57207 43.3044 8.56573 43.2771 8.56154 43.2589C8.55945 43.2499 8.55789 43.2431 8.55687 43.2386C8.55636 43.2363 8.55598 43.2347 8.55574 43.2336C8.55561 43.2331 8.55553 43.2327 8.55547 43.2324C8.55542 43.2322 8.5554 43.2321 8.31152 43.2871C8.06764 43.3421 8.06769 43.3423 8.06778 43.3427C8.06785 43.343 8.06797 43.3435 8.06811 43.3441C8.0684 43.3454 8.06882 43.3473 8.06938 43.3497C8.07049 43.3546 8.07214 43.3618 8.07432 43.3713C8.0787 43.3903 8.08523 43.4184 8.09396 43.4554C8.1114 43.5293 8.13761 43.6388 8.17282 43.7813C8.24324 44.0665 8.34969 44.4842 8.49412 45.0162C8.78299 46.0801 9.22387 47.6013 9.83255 49.4324C11.0496 53.0939 12.9388 57.9989 15.627 62.9685C20.9953 72.8927 29.5929 83.1502 42.4524 84.1596L42.4916 83.6611Z" fill="url(#paint11_linear)"/>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter2_d)">
<path d="M82.6633 99.8944L88.0218 111.216C88.0218 111.216 52.5217 117.209 35.7764 107.22C19.031 97.2306 17.6914 77.252 17.6914 77.252C17.6914 77.252 31.7575 97.2306 48.5028 95.8987C65.2481 94.5668 82.6633 99.8944 82.6633 99.8944Z" fill="url(#paint12_linear)"/>
<path d="M84.6707 105.222C84.6707 105.222 73.9536 103.224 51.8498 103.224C29.746 103.224 17.0195 76.5859 17.0195 76.5859" stroke="url(#paint13_linear)" stroke-width="0.5"/>
</g>
<path d="M92.7088 41.9552L81.9918 59.27L64.9116 48.9477L47.8314 38.6254C47.8314 38.6254 43.9818 27.4383 43.1427 19.9787C42.2409 11.9622 44.4816 0 44.4816 0C44.4816 0 51.1799 15.9829 67.9252 24.6404C84.6704 33.2978 92.7088 41.9552 92.7088 41.9552Z" fill="url(#paint14_linear)"/>
<path d="M44.7284 0.704249C44.7496 0.567802 44.6561 0.440072 44.5196 0.418956C44.3832 0.397841 44.2554 0.491336 44.2343 0.627783L44.7284 0.704249ZM86.6791 51.9446C86.8071 51.7299 86.8071 51.7299 86.8071 51.7298C86.807 51.7298 86.8069 51.7297 86.8068 51.7297C86.8065 51.7295 86.8061 51.7293 86.8055 51.7289C86.8044 51.7282 86.8026 51.7272 86.8002 51.7257C86.7955 51.7229 86.7883 51.7186 86.7787 51.7128C86.7594 51.7012 86.7304 51.6837 86.6918 51.6602C86.6146 51.6133 86.4987 51.5424 86.3449 51.4472C86.0373 51.2567 85.578 50.9687 84.9721 50.5793C83.7604 49.8004 81.9625 48.6157 79.6205 46.9941C74.9364 43.7509 68.0755 38.7597 59.3729 31.771L59.0599 32.1608C67.7718 39.1572 74.6422 44.1554 79.3359 47.4052C81.6827 49.0301 83.4853 50.2179 84.7018 50.9999C85.31 51.3908 85.7717 51.6803 86.0817 51.8723C86.2367 51.9682 86.3537 52.0398 86.4321 52.0875C86.4714 52.1113 86.5009 52.1292 86.5208 52.1411C86.5307 52.1471 86.5382 52.1516 86.5432 52.1546C86.5457 52.1561 86.5476 52.1573 86.5489 52.1581C86.5496 52.1584 86.5501 52.1587 86.5504 52.1589C86.5506 52.159 86.5507 52.1591 86.5508 52.1592C86.5509 52.1592 86.551 52.1593 86.6791 51.9446ZM59.3729 31.771C50.7135 24.8169 47.0565 17.0419 45.5611 11.0114C44.813 7.99469 44.6055 5.41289 44.5848 3.58714C44.5744 2.67435 44.6108 1.95085 44.6495 1.45686C44.6689 1.20988 44.6888 1.02032 44.7038 0.893192C44.7113 0.829632 44.7176 0.781686 44.7219 0.749985C44.7241 0.734134 44.7258 0.722345 44.7269 0.714696C44.7274 0.710871 44.7279 0.708082 44.7281 0.706337C44.7283 0.705465 44.7284 0.704854 44.7284 0.704506C44.7284 0.704331 44.7284 0.704267 44.7285 0.70418C44.7285 0.704181 44.7284 0.704249 44.4814 0.666016C44.2343 0.627783 44.2343 0.627982 44.2343 0.628248C44.2342 0.628424 44.2342 0.628756 44.2341 0.629108C44.234 0.629814 44.2339 0.630784 44.2337 0.632015C44.2333 0.634478 44.2328 0.63799 44.2321 0.642542C44.2308 0.651644 44.2289 0.664903 44.2265 0.682241C44.2218 0.716915 44.2151 0.767904 44.2073 0.834575C44.1915 0.967915 44.1709 1.164 44.151 1.41779C44.1112 1.92534 44.0743 2.66382 44.0848 3.59281C44.1059 5.45063 44.3169 8.0716 45.0758 11.1317C46.5942 17.2549 50.3048 25.1299 59.0599 32.1608L59.3729 31.771Z" fill="url(#paint15_linear)"/>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="4.41406" width="88.0044" height="86.1668" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset dy="4"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter1_d" x="4.06738" y="43.2324" width="83.2632" height="65.3268" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset dy="4"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter2_d" x="12.7939" y="76.4785" width="79.2278" height="44.5204" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset dy="4"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="246.473" y1="-3.32978" x2="189.235" y2="60.2653" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.105076" stop-color="#EEF9FB"/>
<stop offset="0.872084" stop-color="#57B8ED"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="238.434" y1="8.65748" x2="197.157" y2="52.183" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="284.337" y1="40.0715" x2="236.182" y2="123.513" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.105076" stop-color="#EEF9FB"/>
<stop offset="0.872084" stop-color="#57B8ED"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="274.292" y1="50.9692" x2="241.466" y2="113.067" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint4_linear" x1="289.292" y1="0.286716" x2="217.043" y2="98.4234" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.105076" stop-color="#EEF9FB"/>
<stop offset="0.872084" stop-color="#57B8ED"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint5_linear" x1="278.287" y1="15.3539" x2="226.4" y2="89.7545" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint6_linear" x1="274.36" y1="75.2437" x2="251.116" y2="135.739" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.105076" stop-color="#EEF9FB"/>
<stop offset="0.872084" stop-color="#57B8ED"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint7_linear" x1="265.615" y1="81.0487" x2="251.826" y2="122.644" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint8_linear" x1="-6.29192" y1="0.286716" x2="65.9573" y2="98.4233" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.105076" stop-color="#EEF9FB"/>
<stop offset="0.872084" stop-color="#57B8ED"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint9_linear" x1="4.70942" y1="15.3539" x2="56.5956" y2="89.7544" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint10_linear" x1="-1.33907" y1="40.0696" x2="46.8157" y2="123.511" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.105076" stop-color="#EEF9FB"/>
<stop offset="0.872084" stop-color="#57B8ED"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint11_linear" x1="8.70625" y1="50.9672" x2="41.5321" y2="113.065" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint12_linear" x1="8.64398" y1="75.2437" x2="31.8877" y2="135.739" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.105076" stop-color="#EEF9FB"/>
<stop offset="0.872084" stop-color="#57B8ED"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint13_linear" x1="17.3853" y1="81.0487" x2="31.1743" y2="122.644" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint14_linear" x1="36.5249" y1="-3.32978" x2="93.7633" y2="60.2652" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.105076" stop-color="#EEF9FB"/>
<stop offset="0.872084" stop-color="#57B8ED"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint15_linear" x1="44.5619" y1="8.65748" x2="85.8392" y2="52.1829" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity I've simplified a lot your code. You can use what you have with the observation that you have useless paths that you can remove.

The main idea is:

1. transform one of the svg elements in a symbol preserving the viewBox.
2. use the symbol with `<use>`. Since the symbol has a viewBox you can give the `<use>` a width and height attributes for a new size. You can also give the `<use>` a x and y attributes for the position.

In the next example I'm making the hexagon a symbol inside the wings svg element but you can make the wings a symbol inside the hexagon svg.

Please observe that I`ve changed the viewBox value so that you can see the hole hexagon.

Also since you want to make it responsive I've removed the width and height attributes of the svg element. This way the svg element will take all the width available.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 282 135" fill="skyblue" stroke="white">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="hex" viewBox="0 0 260 300">
    <path
      d="M250.042 232.281L138.415 297.09C132.132 300.738 124.366 300.691 118.127 296.97L9.75357 232.319C3.70481 228.71 0 222.186 0 215.143V84.8573C0 77.814 3.7048 71.2899 9.75356 67.6814L118.127 3.03046C124.366 -0.691467 132.132 -0.737547 138.415 2.91007L250.042 67.7185C256.206 71.2974 260 77.8867 260 85.0148V214.985C260 222.113 256.206 228.703 250.042 232.281Z"
      fill="black" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>  
  
<use xlink:href="#hex" width="110" height="110" x="85" y="20" />
 
  
<g id="wings"> 
<g id="right">
<path d="M190.289 41.9552L201.006 59.27L218.086 48.9477L235.167 38.6254C235.167 38.6254 239.016 27.4383 239.855 19.9787C240.757 11.9622 238.516 0 238.516 0C238.516 0 231.818 15.9829 215.073 24.6404C198.328 33.2978 190.289 41.9552 190.289 41.9552Z" />
<path d="M199.667 100.561L203.016 82.5804C203.016 82.5804 219.762 70.5932 241.196 68.5954C262.63 66.5975 274.687 43.2891 274.687 43.2891C274.687 43.2891 271.337 97.8974 237.177 97.8974C203.016 97.8974 199.667 100.561 199.667 100.561Z" />
<path d="M198.995 59.2724L204.355 82.5808C204.355 82.5808 214.403 76.4209 249.233 69.9277C284.062 63.4345 278.703 4.66406 278.703 4.66406C278.703 4.66406 267.989 25.3087 239.187 36.6299C210.385 47.9512 198.995 59.2724 198.995 59.2724Z" />
<path d="M200.341 99.8944L194.982 111.216C194.982 111.216 230.482 117.209 247.228 107.22C263.973 97.2306 265.312 77.252 265.312 77.252C265.312 77.252 251.246 97.2306 234.501 95.8987C217.756 94.5668 200.341 99.8944 200.341 99.8944Z" />
</g>
<g id="left">
<path d="M84.0045 59.2724L78.6452 82.5808C78.6452 82.5808 68.5964 76.4209 33.7674 69.9277C-1.06154 63.4345 4.29675 4.66406 4.29675 4.66406C4.29675 4.66406 15.0114 25.3087 43.8133 36.6299C72.6153 47.9512 84.0045 59.2724 84.0045 59.2724Z" />
<path d="M83.3306 100.559L79.9815 82.5785C79.9815 82.5785 63.2362 70.5913 41.8022 68.5934C20.3682 66.5955 8.31152 43.2871 8.31152 43.2871C8.31152 43.2871 11.6606 97.8955 45.8211 97.8955C79.9815 97.8955 83.3306 100.559 83.3306 100.559Z" />
<path d="M82.6633 99.8944L88.0218 111.216C88.0218 111.216 52.5217 117.209 35.7764 107.22C19.031 97.2306 17.6914 77.252 17.6914 77.252C17.6914 77.252 31.7575 97.2306 48.5028 95.8987C65.2481 94.5668 82.6633 99.8944 82.6633 99.8944Z" />
<path d="M92.7088 41.9552L81.9918 59.27L64.9116 48.9477L47.8314 38.6254C47.8314 38.6254 43.9818 27.4383 43.1427 19.9787C42.2409 11.9622 44.4816 0 44.4816 0C44.4816 0 51.1799 15.9829 67.9252 24.6404C84.6704 33.2978 92.7088 41.9552 92.7088 41.9552Z"  />
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: wow, this is so helpful!! Thanks to your explanation I understand a little more about SVG and I already have the notion of how to add it to my application, really thank you very much 